# Alembic stamp command issues with sqlite in-memory db

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm experiencing some problems with alembic's stamp command and using sqlite in-memory databases for testing. Tests that work perfectly with file-based sqlite dbs fail with `OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table`.

I'm stamping during initialisation to show the database is up-to-date:

```
def init_db(engine, version):
    tables.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    with engine.begin() as connection:
        stamp_alembic(connection)

def stamp_alembic(connection):
    from alembic import command
    from alembic.config import Config

    alembic_cfg = Config('alembic.ini')
    alembic_cfg.attributes['connection'] = connection
    command.stamp(alembic_cfg, 'head')
```

I'm passing the current connection to `env.py` [as per the cookbook](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html#sharing-a-connection-with-a-series-of-migration-commands-and-environments):

```
def run_migrations_online():
    connectable = config.attributes.get('connection', None)
    if connectable is None:
        # only create Engine if we don't have a Connection
        # from the outside
        connectable = engine_from_config(
            config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
            prefix='sqlalchemy.',
            poolclass=pool.NullPool
        )
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

My test class:

```
SETTINGS = {'sqlalchemy.url': 'sqlite:///:memory:'}

class TestOperatorUserModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        engine = engine_from_config(SETTINGS, 'sqlalchemy.')
        tables.DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
        init_db(engine, SETTINGS['version.db'])
        transaction.begin()

    def tearDown(self):
        engine = engine_from_config(SETTINGS, 'sqlalchemy.')
        transaction.abort()
        tables.Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        tables.DBSession.remove()
```

If I remove the stamp call from initialisation, the tests also run fine. As a workaround, I'm only stamping the db if `engine.url.database` isn't `':memory:'`, but I'd ideally like to know what is the real source of the issue.

Environment is Python 2.7.11, SQLAlchemy 0.9.10, alembic 0.8.6 and sqlite 2.8.17.